# Using GitLab Runner to build projects without using Docker

Tags: c++, cmake, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Is it possible to add a CI/CD in your GitLab project without using Docker that does the following things:

1. Build the project using CMake.
2. Upload binaries to a Conan server

If I were to make a shell executor with a locally running GitLab Runner, is there a way to make it have CMake and Conan?

.gitlab-ci.yml pretty basic example to test if `conan` and `cmake` are present.

```
stages:
    - build
    - publish

cmake_build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - mkdir build
        - cd build
        - conan
        - cmake
    tags:
        - build
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Just install it.

Comment: I install it through the script? in `before_script`? On my local machine? What exactly is the procedure?

Comment: You install it on the machine that is running gitlab-runner. `I install it through the script? in before_script?` No... well, you could give ex. the user sudo access, but that you would do modifications to your system. Maybe you should re-read shell executor gitlab-runner documentation.  `On my local machine?` On the machine where gitlab-runner is running. `What exactly is the procedure?` Linux has extensive history of package managers. Compiler from source or install using the system package manger, just like with any other thing installed on a linux system.

Comment: I already have conan and cmake installed in my machine where my runner is running, but just calling the command `conan` or `cmake` gives me an error when it runs in my .gitlab-ci.yml script. I'll edit it into my thread so you can see it. I've also made sure that the runner that's running the job is my local one and not a shared one.

Comment: Then you are asking XY question - you do not ask "is it possible..." but your question  maybe is "how do I fix this and that..". Please do not ask XY question. Please read [ask]. Please create an [MCVE] of your problem. `gives me an error` What _exactly_ gives you which error? Are you sure the job uses your runner? Why are you sure? Your ./gitlab-ci.yml you posted is invalid - `script:` is missing.

Comment: That was my fault, I pasted it wrong. Please have a look again. Either way, my original question was asking if it was possible to do it without docker which seems to be the case since you told me I only have to install these programs on my local machine that's running GitLab runner. That's a good thing for me, so I tried to set up the gitlab-ci.yml, already having `conan` and `cmake` installed on my machine, and followed up with another question related to what you told me: why is my script not recognizing `conan` nor `cmake` when it runs? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The error comes when the script tries to execute `conan` and says it's not a recognized command.

Comment: I'm sure I'm using the correct runner because the ID of the runner that's used matches with my local Runner that I see in Settings > CI/CD  > Runners

Comment: `the correct runner because the ID of the runner that's used matches with my local Runner that I see in Settings > CI/CD > Runners` so you added the runner to the project, does not mean the runner is used. The runner ID is visible _in run job view in gitlab_ when running on top right in `Runner: <the name>`. Limit available runners to the job with `tags:` in gitlab-ci.yml . The simplest is to add `hostname` to the `script:` and see if it's really it. Try with the full path to `conan`, maybe it's not in path.

Comment: `Try with the full path to conan, maybe it's not in path.` This ended up being the problem. Thank you